# CMake-provided variables not found

Tags: cmake

Is it possible for CMake to be unable to read its own variables ([cmake-variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-variables.7.html#cmake-variables-7))? If so, what is the real problem behind this?

I was trying to configure a CMake project that requires OpenCV 4, so in my project CMakeLists.txt I have:

```bash
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
message("version ${CMAKE_VERSION}")

project(myproject)
find_package(OpenCV 4)
if(NOT OpenCV_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "ORB_SLAM3 requires OpenCV 4, to use OpenCV 3 switch to the main branch")
endif()

find_package(OpenCV 4)
if(NOT OpenCV_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "ORB_SLAM3 requires OpenCV 4, to use OpenCV 3 switch to the main branch")
endif()

add_executable(${TARGET_NAME}
    src/main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} PUBLIC
    ${OpenCV_LIBS}
)
```

However the CMake configuration process always ended up with an error:

```bash
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/opencv4/OpenCVModules.cmake:7 (message):
  CMake >= 2.8.3 required
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/opencv4/OpenCVConfig.cmake:174 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:19 (find_package)
```

I have CMake 3.26.1 installed, and with other CMakeLists.txt I can print the CMake version number just fine, which makes me wonder the root cause of this error message. I ultimately tried to show the `CMAKE_VERSION` that CMake sees when parsing `OpenCVModules.cmake` by changing line 7 in this file to:

```bash
# OpenCVModules.cmake
message(FATAL_ERROR "CMake >= 2.8.3 required, current version is ${CMAKE_VERSION}")
```

and the result (error messsage) is:

```bash
CMake >= 2.8.3 required, current version is
```

which means that the variable CMAKE_VERSION was not detected at all. I tried printing `CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION` and `CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION` and none of the real values were shown.

Comment: does your root CMakeLists.txt contain a  [cmake_minimum_required](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_minimum_required.html) statement ?
e.g. `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)` also, try posting a minimal, reproducable example of your CMakeLists.txt

Comment: From the description of [CMAKE_VERSION](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_VERSION.html) variable: "The CMAKE_VERSION variable is defined by CMake 2.6.3 and higher. Earlier versions defined only the individual component variables." That is, even very very old CMake defines `CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION` variable. Empty variable means something very strange with your setup. Or it could be that some of your code clears the value of `CMAKE_VERSION` variable. In any case, you need to provide much more information about your case.

Comment: @ChrisB I have updated the answer with a minimal CMakelists.txt, and yes I did have cmake_minimum_required at the top.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you, what more information would be helpful to investigate the root cause in this case?

Comment: Can you compare your `OpenCVModules.cmake` to -- say -- the latest from the opencv project?  It might be a bug with that exact version that your operating system provides.

Comment: It's also always a good idea to clear your `CMakeCache.txt` (or if paranoid, from a new directory) between tests.  Although it's not common for an internal CMAKE variable to be lost, the build system can do some caching when you least expect it.

Comment: If a variable has been defined at some point, but later it becomes undefined or empty, then by using [variable_watch](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/variable_watch.html) you could find the place of the variable's modification. In the simple form you could place a call to `variable_watch(CMAKE_VERSION)` at the beginning of your script and look for one of access: MODIFIED_ACCESS, UNKNOWN_MODIFIED_ACCESS, or REMOVED_ACCESS.